# Display a specific Unicode character on different Android version

Tags: android, android-typeface

I'm currently trying to display a specific Unicode character`("\u24BA",Ⓔ)` that I receive from my API and try to display it in a TextView.

The display work perfectly on Android 5+. However, when I try on Android 4.2 and 4.4 I got different behavior.

Android 4.2 replace the character by an empty String.
Android 4.4 replace the character by a uppercase E.

My initial though was that Android 4+ font doesn't handle this Unicode character and I decided to implement a Typeface with `Roboto_Medium.ttf`

```
Typeface medium = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto-Medium.ttf");
name.setTypeface(medium);
name.setText("Ⓔ");  or name.setText(Html.fromHtml("\u24BA");
```

I got the exact same result as describe above.

Any idea ?